# AspCore 404 on production enviroment

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

When I create AspCore Hosted Blazor Wasm template project(VS22) and change server's launchSettings.json aspnetcore enviroment to "Production" or delete it entirely, page gets 404. It runs fine on "Development". Am i missing something? Do i need to configure anything else to run the app on production enviroment?

Comment: The first user votedown to close the post , why would you votedown this question with the answer? Op does have a problem, it may be caused by the specific version or environmental factors, we share to solve the problem, isn't SO users should do? Are you in a bad mood?

Answer (score 2):

In my case helped adding `StaticWebAssetsLoader.UseStaticWebAssets()` to `Program.cs` in `BlazorApp.Server.proj`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StaticWebAssets;
...

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

StaticWebAssetsLoader.UseStaticWebAssets(builder.Environment, builder.Configuration);

...
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't know the content in your `launchSettings.json`. And I follow your steps  to try, and can't reproduce the issue.

So my suggestion is you need upgrade your VS2022 to latest version first.

1. Then you can create another new sample project to test.
2. If you not use the latest .net core version, please use .net6. (Same as mine)

**My Test Steps:**

1. Delete the environment like below:

   ```
   {
   "iisSettings": {
     "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:14136",
      "sslPort": 44320
    }
   },
   "profiles": {
    "BlazorApp1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7060;http://localhost:5060",
      "environmentVariables": {

      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "environmentVariables": {

      }
    }
   }
   }
   ```
2. Run it in VS2022, and it works well.
3. Publish it, and host in IIS.

   [image]

Comment: Sorry for missing information, I did exactly what you did. Fresh aspcore hosted blazor wasm app on updated vs22 with .net6. Both Kestrel and IssExpress gets 404 on production enviroment. Https upgrading works somehow tho.